# flask-sqlachemy: can't make parent listen and update on changes to a child

Tags: python, events, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a test I'm trying to pass:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('db')
def new_scan_service(db):
    user = User.create(username='Princess Leia', email='dontatme@me.com')
    date = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
    experiment1 = Experiment.create(date=date, scanner='GE', num_scans=2, user_id=user.id)
    experiment2 = Experiment.create(date=date, scanner='GE', num_scans=2, user_id=user.id)
    db.session.commit()
    print('I just put the user and two experiments into the database', user.num_experiments)
    s = ScanService(user.id, experiment2.id)
    return s

class TestScanUpload:

    def test_xnat_ids_correctly_generated_for_multiple_experiments_and_scans(self, new_scan_service):
        """
        Given a subject with more than one experiment, and an experiment with more than one scan
        When xnat ids are generated
        Then test that xnat_experiment_id and xnat_scan_id are as expected
        """

        with open('<file-path>', 'r') as f:
            xnat_ids = new_scan_service._generate_xnat_identifiers()
            assert xnat_ids['experiment']['xnat_id'] == '000001_MR2'
```

`user.num_experiments` should increment by one every time I get a new experiment.  I read somewhere on Stack Overflow that this was faster than doing a query every time you wanted to know how many experiments a user has.

I am trying to use `sqlachemy.event` to listen for the creation of an experiment and update `user.num_experiments`.

Here's one thing I've tried.  I put this code in the module that defines the Experiment model:

```
def update_user_exp_count(mapper, connection, target):
    db.session.begin_nested()
    user_id = target.user_id
    print("user id is ", user_id)
    user = User.get_by_id(user_id)
    user.num_experiments += 1
    print("This is my listener.  user.num experiments is", user.num_experiments)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

event.listen(Experiment, 'before_insert', update_user_exp_count)
```

The test fails with an assertion error, and here's my standard out:

```
user id is  1
This is my listener.  user.num experiments is 1
user id is  1
This is my listener.  user.num experiments is 1
I just put the user and two experiments into the database. user.num_experiments is  0
```

So my listener got called, but the user object was never updated in the database table in a persistent way.

I also tried following the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229410/how-to-update-parent-table-timestamp-when-child-table-is-modified).

Here's the relevant part of the User model.

```
class User(UserMixin, SurrogatePK, Model):
    """A user of the app."""

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    username = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    num_experiments = Column(db.Integer(), default=0)
    experiments = relationship('Experiment', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
```

And of the Experiment model (`reference_col` is a function defined in cookiecutter flask for inserting foreign keys):

```
class Experiment(SurrogatePK, Model):
    """A user's experiment, during which they are scanned."""

__tablename__ = 'experiments'
date = Column(db.Date(), nullable=False)
scanner = Column(db.String(80), nullable=True)
num_scans = Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)
user_id = reference_col('users', nullable=True)
```

I put this code in the module that defines the User model:

```
  @event.listens_for(User.experiments, 'append')
    def receive_append(target, value, initiator):
        print("I was executed")
        target.num_experiments += 1
```

This never gets executed.

What do I have to do to make the parent listen for new children and update itself when it gets them?  I'd appreciate any help you can provide.

UPDATE:  I have developed a way to work around this issue.  But I'm still interested to know why I can't use listeners.  Here's my workaround:

```
class ExperimentService:

    def add(self, user, date, scanner, num_scans):
        exp = Experiment.create(date=date, scanner=scanner, num_scans=num_scans, user_id=user.id)
        user.update(num_experiments=user.num_experiments + 1)
        print("here I am in the add function. user.num_experiments is ", user.num_experiments)
        return exp
```

`.update` is one of the convenience methods provided by cookiecutter flask.  When I do this, my test passes.  So my questions remaining are:

Why, even though `update_user_exp_count` is executed, do the changes not seem to persist in the database?

and

Why is `receive_append` never executed?

Comment: As I understood `new_scan_service` is your main test which describe behavior?

Comment: the test is the method that starts 'test'.  `new_scan_service` is just generating a scan service object for that test to use.  However, I should update this, because I came to understand part of my own problem, and the way I asked my question would make it hard for anyone on SO to see it.  The only thing left I don't understand is why my listener didn't execute.

Comment: you can remove test and add steps what are you doing.

Comment: I don't think removing the test is going to improve the clarity of my question. Maybe if someone else comes by and also asks me to remove it I will. Anyway, I was partially wrong in my previous comment. I still have all the problems described in the post, I realized. I just worked around them. I'm going to edit the post so it reflects some new understandings, but all these problems seem to still exists

Comment: I understand your problem... But. So long description for reproducing... Why you can't create 2 models, 1 listener and just script? Without any `tests` and `prints`? You need just 1 hook and that's all. 90% successful answer depends on the question...

Comment: I mean... Small and quick example for reproduce is the best way. `TestScanUpload`, `new_scan_service`, `ExperimentService` are details.